# Is there a canonical fork of mustache.js?

Tags: github, mustache

I'm looking at pulling mustache.js into a project, and a quick glance at [its network graph](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/network) revealed that it has a ton of heavily-committed-to forks.

Are any of these considered canonical/preferable? Or am I best off starting with a download of janl's original distribution until I need something from a fork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is always a tough one.  If the root repo does what you need and doesn't seem buggy, it's best to start there.  Unless the owner of the root repo has specifically stated that active development has been passed on to a specific fork.  You can always explore forks later, or even make your own fork and pull the stuff you want in to it.